# How do I write a Query in retrofit2 GET URL with special characters?

Tags: android, url, retrofit2

I am trying to make a URL in android and I am using retrofit2. My query field is "field[name]".
When I print the URL it created it shows: "baseURL?filter" and then the rest is not in the URL.
When I tried using the enncoded form: filter%5Bname%5D, it took % and converted it into %25.

Comment: Did you try ``@Query(value="filter%5Bname%5D", encoded=true)`` to tell retrofit that you are passing both a parameter name and value already encoded?

Comment: @Fred The query field name is "field[name]" the value that I have to pass is a variable String

Comment: oh I was confused by your question. On one place you say ``filter`` and in the other ``field``, sorry. Well try to use whatever name you need, but important part is if you pass it encoded then tell retrofit it's already encoded by doing ``encoded=true``

Comment: @Fred Thank you. It actually works. and my apologies, just now I noticed that I have accidentally written two different names. Its because I was using both the variable names in my code for different purposes.

Comment: No worries, glad it's working now